# Dynamodb scan with condition

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamodb like this:

```
TableName : "User",
KeySchema: [       
    { AttributeName: "id", KeyType: "HASH"}  //Partition key
],
AttributeDefinitions: [       
    { AttributeName: "id", AttributeType: "S" }
],
ProvisionedThroughput: {       
    ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
    WriteCapacityUnits: 10
}
```

Now I am trying to search a user:

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'User',
    FilterExpression: 'contains(id, :value)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':value': 'ronaldo'
    }
};

dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

It's very simple, but I got a lot errors:

```
"message": "Expected params.ExpressionAttributeValues['value'] to be a structure"
```

Anyone got this ?

Comment: I got this. Just change
':value': 'ronaldo'
to 
':value': {'S':'ronaldo'}

Comment: otherwise you can use the documentclient in node

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code:
I got the same issue.
Here structure meaning **we should supply DataType** while passing the value to It.

```
        var params = {
            TableName: 'User',
            FilterExpression: 'contains(id, :value)',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':value': {
                    'S': 'ronaldo'
                }
            }
        };

        dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
            else ppJson(data); // successful response
        });
```

Where **S means String** Data type.